# Many for loops, but PyQT5 Output Text

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am switching from Python Console to a Python App/Programm.
I was using `for loops` with many prints.
I switched to PyQT5 with an Output Text aka. as Label
here is an example of my for loops:

```
        i = 0
        for x in data['data']:
            rank = data['data'][i]["currenttierpatched"]
            rr = data['data'][i]["mmr_change_to_last_game"]
            date = data['data'][i]["date"]
            print(f"{date}\n{rank} {rr}rr")
            i += 1
```

I only have one Output Text, now how can i like get all the things i get from the for loop with only one command so i have one line of code for the Output Text?
Because i cant get the for loop in one single Text, you know what i mean?

Comment: Sorry, but, no, we don't know what you mean. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and consider [edit]ing your post by providing a proper [mre] that would clarify what you're currently doing. Also, don't overuse data structures, especially if they only make your code more cryptic than it could (or should) be.

Comment: It might help to hardcode the value of data so we can see what's wrong. But it seems weird that your for loop is giving you x, but you are using i ... whatever that is.

Comment: Create a list (e.g. `mylist = []`) before the loop, then instead of printing the text, do `mylist.append(text)`. After the loop, you can then do `text = '\n'.join(mylist)` to get a single block of text which can be shown in a text-edit (or whatever).

Comment: okay! can you please do it in a answer and not in a comment? so i  can give you the check mark?

Comment: Also, for future reference you can use `for i,x in enumerate(data['data']):` to get the index automatically without having to manage it yourself.

Comment: @Navis I didn't post an answer because it wasn't clear from your question exactly what you wanted. Also, if you want to notify a specific user in comments, make sure you use `@username`. I only saw your comment this time by accident.

Comment: Oh okay! Im sorry @wyattg71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the Person from a comment doesnt answer this Post.
Im gonna answer it.

I simply made a List with
`list = []`
and instead of printing in every for loop i used `list.append("Text")`
at the end i made a new variable called `Text` and used `"".join(list)`
then in my Output Lable i simply used:
`self.DOutputText.setText(f"{text}")`

So it would be:

```
        list = []
        if data['status'] == 200:
            for x in data['data']:
                rank = data['data'][i]["currenttierpatched"]
                rr = data['data'][i]["mmr_change_to_last_game"]
                date = data['data'][i]["date"]
                list.append(f"{date}\n{rank} {rr}rr\n")
                i += 1
            text = "".join(list)
            self.COutputText.setText(f"{text}")
        else:
            self.COutputText.setText(f"Error | {data['status']}\n{data['message']}")
```

Thanks for you help!

**EDIT**
With the comment from wyattg71, i removed the i variable and edited the for loop.

```
        list = []
        if data['status'] == 200:
            for i, x in data['data']:
                rank = data['data'][i]["currenttierpatched"]
                rr = data['data'][i]["mmr_change_to_last_game"]
                date = data['data'][i]["date"]
                list.append(f"{date}\n{rank} {rr}rr\n")
            text = "".join(list)
            self.COutputText.setText(f"{text}")
        else:
            self.COutputText.setText(f"Error | {data['status']}\n{data['message']}")
```

Comment: Did this work? I was thinking
`for i, x in enumerate(data['data']):` where the index `i` is returned by the `enumerate` function.
See [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) for more info on that. Just trying to help simplify, your first method works just as well! I recommend using what you're comfortable with.